# Why does LaTeX change font each time I compile?

Tags: fonts, compiling

First time I compile the document the font in the entire document is the one specified for the section titles (larger than it should be in the rest of the document etc.) and some characters are wrong. For example dots (in list) are exchanged for Z and scandinavian letters (ä, ö, etc) are missing.

If I compile the document three times the text is printed as specified, except for the table descriptions. One more compilation makes even that ok, and then it starts all over again.

I have tried googling the problem, asking colleagues, but no luck yet. If you have any suggestions I would be forever grateful!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Not using babel. It's a huge file by now, something happened to it the last time I added text (just copied text from Word, collaborating with two people where one refuses to use Word and the other one refuses to use anything else but Word). It is based on an Elsevier template, what would be useful to include in an example for you to see?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.