# Font changes in latex output file after each compilation

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am using Texshop version 2.47 in Mac. Recently I copied some text from somewhere and then it started to change the font (many mathematical/greek symbols started to change in strange signs and the font also changes entirely). Its not giving any warnings or any errors at the time of compilation. I tried deleting the aux files but no use! After at least 10-12 compilations, I am getting the desired font which is quite annoying. I found similar questions on tex.stackexchange without any answer [Why does LaTeX change font each time I compile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23457/)
Some screenshots are attached showing the settings of my file for further description.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I tried googling and didn't get any explanation anywhere. If somebody please can help me regarding this matter, I'll be highly grateful!

My example is the following:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper] {report}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\title{\huge Something important}
\author{{\large Me}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
The example $\omega$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The screenshots are very nice, but do not really provide a clue to solution ;-)

Comment: Screenshots of your software are not helpfull, because TeXshop is just the editor, but the PDF is made by a TeX-engine. Please make sure you understand the difference. So there is no other way than to write a MWE from code as asked in the comment of Christian Hupfer. By the way, you are using xelatex - did you choose to use that?

Comment: Not very relevant wrt ``TeX``, but please see the [Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5775) for how to take screen captures of the active window (and not your entire screen as you are doing here).

Comment: It could be possible that you have a strange file encoding. You might want to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or an alternative option (e.g. `latin1`).

Comment: Your settings don't make any sense. You've set a personal script but seem not to be using it. You appear to be using regular `latex` rather than `pdflatex` but then load `pdfpages` which certainly won't work in that case. Please try compiling at the command line to see if that works. If it does, you can figure out the issue with your settings if not, you will at least know how you tried to compile and can tell us. Also, that is not an MWE unless you can reproduce the error *only* by including *all* of those packages, which I seriously doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your responses. Somehow it could sound strange but this is what it happened. I tried to copy some text from some of the journal paper and then the problem was occurring. It was fixed just by a simple restart of my computer. It happened to me yesterday and happened the same today. So, I was able to point out the problem. 
Thanks again,
Soma

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).